# Save spanned text in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, html, sharedpreferences, spanned

I have a ListView with Spanned items. 
As this concept:

```
 Spanned Test = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.teststring));
```

is very slow I would like to save these Spanned in SharedPreferences.
The problem is that I can only save strings and lose the entire html formatting. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: use `Test.toString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Html.toHtml()` to convert a `Spanned` back into HTML, then save the resulting HTML string in your `SharedPreferences`.

Note, though, that not everything supported by `fromHtml()` is also supported by `toHtml()` (and vice versa).